# Passenger quota or passengers quota?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

One question please.

I am translating a web form into english.
In this specific case what is correct?

**Passenger quota** or **Passengers quota** ?

**Vehicle quota** or **Vehicles quota** ?

Thanks!

Comment: In virtually all contexts you would use the singular form.

Comment: Sorry if a similar question has been already asked. Anyway wasn't that easy to reach that through a search. This can be another specific question. Doesn't do harm do leave it IMHO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IMO, this question belongs to [English Languages Learners SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

But I would say singular is appropriate here, so :

- Passenger quota
- Vehicle quota